# How to implement GROWTH function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to implement Microsoft Excel's [GROWTH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/growth-function-HA102753003.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102752955) function in JavaScript. This function calculates predicted exponential growth by using existing data. What makes it tricky is that it must work with multiple sets of `known_x's` values. I could not find any reference equation. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You might ask [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a reimplementation based on [my answer at math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/270460) and the [simple linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) formulas from the Wikipedia page:

```
function growth ( known_y, known_x, new_x, use_const ) {
    // default values for optional parameters:
    if ( typeof( known_x ) == 'undefined' ) {
        known_x = [];
        for ( var i = 1; i <= known_y.length; i++ ) known_x.push(i);
    }
    if ( typeof( new_x ) == 'undefined' ) {
        new_x = [];
        for ( var i = 1; i <= known_y.length; i++ ) new_x.push(i);
    }
    if ( typeof( use_const ) == 'undefined' ) use_const = true;

    // calculate sums over the data:
    var n = known_y.length;
    var avg_x = 0; var avg_y = 0; var avg_xy = 0; var avg_xx = 0; 
    for ( var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        var x = known_x[i]; var y = Math.log( known_y[i] );
        avg_x += x; avg_y += y; avg_xy += x*y; avg_xx += x*x;
    }
    avg_x /= n; avg_y /= n; avg_xy /= n; avg_xx /= n;

    // compute linear regression coefficients:
    if ( use_const ) {
        var beta = (avg_xy - avg_x*avg_y) / (avg_xx - avg_x*avg_x);
        var alpha = avg_y - beta*avg_x;
    } else {
        var beta = avg_xy / avg_xx;
        var alpha = 0;
    }
    // console.log("alpha = " + alpha + ", beta = " +  beta);

    // compute and return result array:
    var new_y = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < new_x.length; i++ ) {
        new_y.push( Math.exp( alpha + beta * new_x[i] ) );
    }
    return new_y;
}
```

[Here's a demo on ideone.com.](http://ideone.com/4nxukT) You can compare the output with the demo worksheet on the [Excel `GROWTH` documentation page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/growth-function-HA102753003.aspx).

Note that the numerical stability of the summation loop in the algorithm could be improved using techniques such as those described on the Wikipedia page for [calculating the variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance), like [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).  However, for simple examples like this, the naive summation loop is quite good enough.

Comment: You rock! Thanks a ton. I used your code and gave you credit at http://stoic.com/formula and in the codebase at http://stoic.com/formula/lib/formula.js